# Multiple where condition in typeorm

Tags: sql, typescript, typeorm

```
FROM customers
WHERE favorite_website = 'techonthenet.com'
AND customer_id > 6000;
```

How to implement this in typeorm querybuilder?

Comment: Hi, you have to make some examples of codes and describe your errors. Please make more search for your question. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [*queryBuilder & where*](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/adding-where-expression) documentation for more information.

Without parameters:

```js
const customers = await customerRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("customer")
    .where(`customer.favorite_website = 'techonthenet.com'`)
    .andWhere(`customer.customer_id > 6000`)
    .getMany();
```

With parameters:

```js
const customers = await customerRepository
    .createQueryBuilder("customer")
    .where(`customer.favorite_website = :website`, { website: "techonthenet.com")
    .andWhere(`customer.customer_id > :id`, { id: 6000 })
    .getMany();
```